# shortcut counting methods in pandas dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

this is my data-frame

```
    year2000_bin    year2001_bin    year2002_bin    Firm
0   binZ            binZ            binZ            0
1   binZ            binZ            binZ            1
2   binZ            binZ            binZ            2
3   binZ            binZ            binZ            3
4   binZ            binZ            binZ            4
5   binZ            binZ            binZ            5
6   binW            binV            binV            6
7   binZ            binZ            binZ            7
8   binZ            binZ            binZ            8
9   binZ            binZ            binZ            9
```

I am trying to find total number of Firm belonging to each bin (eg binZ, binW, etc)

following syntax gives me for two years

```
dict1={k:list(v) for k, v in rebinnedDF.groupby('year2000_bin')['Firm'] }       
dict2={k:list(v) for k, v in rebinnedDF.groupby('year2001_bin')['Firm'] }

year1= [(k, len(v1)) for k, v1 in dict1.items()]
year2= [(k, len(v2)) for k, v2 in dict2.items()] 
for i in year1:
    #print(i[0])
    for j in year2:
        if i[0]==j[0]:
            print(j[0], i[1], j[1])
```

I can get result

```
(binZ, 9, 9)
(binW, 1, 0)
(binV, 0, 1)
```

my expected result is:

```
(binZ, 9, 9, 9)
(binW, 1, 0, 0)
(binV, 0, 1, 1)
```

Meaning that I have column headers year2000_bin,    year2001_bin,   year2002_bin through year2018_bin so total of 19 years. How do I count that multiple columns for that chosen row value. Looking for an efficient way from panda gurus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.melt('Firm').groupby(['value','variable']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[51]: 
variable  year2000_bin  year2001_bin  year2002_bin
value                                             
binV                 0             1             1
binW                 1             0             0
binZ                 9             9             9
```